# Gradle for Android, how to replace content on XML files for a given variant

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am quite new with Gradle and I haven't got much experience with Maven either.

I have a build script that creates different flavours and different versions (debug, preprod, release).

I have already changed values dynamically using buildConfig class, but now I need to the value DEBUG to ERROR in the producion version in both flavours src/main/res/xml/config.xml.

config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log level="DEBUG"/>
```

build.gradle file:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '1.8'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("keystore")
            storePassword "xxx"
            keyAlias "xxx"
            keyPassword "xxx"
        }

        preprod {
            storeFile file("keystore")
            storePassword "xxx"
            keyAlias "xxx"
            keyPassword "xxx"
        }
    }



    buildTypes {

        debug {
            def variable_1 = 'xxx'

            buildConfig "public static final String VARIABLE_1 = \"$variable_1\";";
        }

        preprod {
            def variable_1 = 'yyy'

            buildConfig "public static final String VARIABLE_1 = \"$variable_1\";";
        }

        release {
            def variable_1 = 'zzz'

            buildConfig "public static final String VARIABLE_1 = \"$variable_1\";";
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releas
        }

        productFlavors {

            one {
                packageName "com.test.one"
            }

            two {
                packageName "com.test.two"
            }
        }



        android.sourceSets.one{

            res {
                srcDir 'one'
            }

            assets {
                srcDir 'one/assets'
            }

            manifest {
                srcFile "src/one/AndroidManifest.xml"
            }

        }

        android.sourceSets.two {
            res {
                srcDir 'two'
            }

            assets {
                srcDir 'two/assets'
            }

            manifest {
                srcFile "src/two/AndroidManifest.xml"
            }

        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

Comment: I've just tried using Gradle's copy function copy the file with the new content when creating the dev version, and copying another one when creating the release version with ERROR as value, even though it does change the file the content doesn't seem to be updated. it looks like the file is compiled before I do that call.